# How to add composeAsync to angular 5 validators

Tags: angular, forms, angular-validation

I'm working on an Angular 5 forms module using reactive forms approach. In that form for one of my form controls, I need some back-end validation to be done,
Can someone help to implement composeAsync function handle back-end validations?

Comment: You possibly need this: https://alligator.io/angular/async-validators/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I implemented (for username check)

First I have added a report validation function for remort validation

```
this.regForm = this.fb.group({
      userName: ['', Validators.required, 
                 this.validateUserIDNotTaken.bind(this) ],
      password: [ '', [Validators.required]]
});
```

then

```
validateUserIDNotTaken(control: AbstractControl) {
    return this.userService.validateUserIDNotTaken(control.value).map(res => {
      return res ? null : { unTaken: true };
    });
}
```

in user service

```
export class validateUserIDNotTaken{
  static createValidator(userService: UserService) {
    return (control: AbstractControl) => {
      return userService.validateUserIDNotTaken(control.value).map(res => {
        return res ? null : { unTaken: true };
      });
    };
  }
}
```

and added this to the template

```
<div *ngIf="regForm.get('userName').errors && regForm .get('userName').errors.unTaken">
   This userName is already taken!
</div>
```